# Android - Paypal Payouts in Android?

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

Does anyone know if it is possible to use Paypal Payouts in an Android app? For example the app user builds up money in their app account. They then decide that they would like to withdraw that money, go to withdraw, enter their paypal account and then their paypal account is credited with the money from their app account (which would come from another paypal account).
This would work very similarly to a gambling/casino/poker type app.
Does anyone know if this is possible using the Paypal Mobile SDK? Or should I use something else and head in a different direction?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but is the [Payouts API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payouts) what you might be looking for?

Comment: Possibly. It looks like it could be the right thing but can it be used with Android?

Comment: Are you planning on publishing such an app to the Play Store? I've had one of my apps deleted for using Paypal as a payment system before.

Comment: Yeah that was the plan. Oh really? Is it against Google terms?

Comment: Could this be what I'm looking for? https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/ Chained Payments using Adaptive Pay looks like what I'm after but not sure if this can be used on android?

Comment: @PaulAlexander It should. It's a REST API. Should be easy to use.

Comment: awesome I'll have to give that a try then. I've seen other apps using it so I can't see it being a problem. Just wanted to check before I get too far down the development road